# DeleteAsync MobileServices Timed out

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have the following code.

The C# code is on the device, Windows Phone 8:

```
IMobileServiceTable<Subscription> SubsciptionsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Subscription>();
SubscriptionItemServerItem = await SubsciptionsTable.Where(subs => subs.userId == App.UserInfromationID && subs.ContentID == holdElement.NewMessages).ToListAsync();//only want items that are something
await SubsciptionsTable.DeleteAsync(SubscriptionItemServerItem[0]);
```

Where I send the delete request to the Azure MobileService.
Here I have the following Script:

```
    function del(id, user, request) {
    var TableA_Table = tables.getTable('subscription');

    //console.log("About to Delete Subscription:", id);
    TableA_Table.where({ userId: user.userId, id: id})
        .read ({ success: DeleteItem });

    function DeleteItem(results)
    {
        if(results > 0){
            console.log("Reached HERE", id);
            request.execute();
        }
    }
    }
```

I am using this script to verify the user is allowed to delete what he is requesting, i.e. That the userdeleting has the userId matching the userId in the Table.

Everything works and I reach the

```
    request.execute();
```

But then it hangs and my await on the phone, times out.
And the item is not deleted on the server either.

What Should I do? And what could cause the error?

**Solution**

I still did not find the error in my script. But by tweaking the response I got, that I marked as answered I found the solution to be:

```
function del(id, user, request) 
{
  var table = tables.getTable('subscription');

  table.where({ id: id }).read({
    success: function (results) 
    {
      if (results.length > 0) 
      {
        //console.log("log existingItem",results[0].userId);
        //console.log("log user",user.userId);
        if (results[0].userId == user.userId) 
        {
          request.execute();
        } 
        else 
        {
          // console.log("Invalid user");
          request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid user");
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        // console.log("NOT_FOUND");
        request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
      }
    }, error: function () {
      //console.log("NOT_FOUND_error");
      request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your "delete" function to this:

```
function delete(item, user, request) 
{
    var table = tables.getTable('subscription');
    table.where({ id: item.id }).read({
    success: function (results) 
    {
        if (results.length) 
        {
            var existingItem = results[0];
            if (existingItem.UserId === user.userId) 
            {
                request.execute();
            } 
            else 
            {
                request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid user");
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }, error: function () {
    request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: I had to tweak your script. But I still do not understand what was wrong with mine since I reached the request.execute();.

I have another question if you can answer that. If I want to delete elements from another table because of what I deleted here. How would I go about it.
I mean I would get the table search for the relevant info. And then I would have a list of elements that fit my specifications. How do I delete this?

Comment: Since it's not relational database you must search and delete manually. I'll try to code something for you asap.

Comment: That Would be awesome, I tried some stuff unfortunately with no success.

Answer (score 1):

call the function below after the line "request.execute();"

```
 var sqlSpecs = "DELETE from specifications WHERE subscriptionId = " + id;
 mssql.query(sqlSpecs, {
 success: function()
    {
        console.log("ok");
    },
    error: function(err)
    {
        console.log("there was a problem deleting specifications with subscriptionId: " + id + ", " + err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay Thank you. But as my sql knowledge is very limited. Can you explain what is happening. 
I do not just want to add code I cannot follow :)
Further do I need to add something in sqlSpecs?
I need to delete after id, but it should be paired with contentId in the other Table.

Comment: I created sqlSpecs and it is a sql statement. I don't know the columns of your table, so I imagined that you have a specifications table and it has a columns that store subscription Id. Am I wrong? after that, I just call the sql statement inside mssql.query. It should works. Another option: after await SubsciptionsTable.DeleteAsync(SubscriptionItemServerItem[0]); call a DeleteAsync in Specifications Table. Maybe it will be more simple.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx the official doc about the mssql object. Cheers

Comment: another option: recreate your table with " ON DELETE CASCADE ", then after delete Subscription it will delete child data too. ALTER TABLE dbo.Specifications
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Subscription_Specification_Cascade
   FOREIGN KEY (SubscriptionID) REFERENCES dbo.Subscription(SubscriptionID) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: The Last Idea you write I have not been able to find when setting the information in Azure.
But I will Try your second answer and see if I can get it to work.
Thank you!

Comment: I can't get your SQL code to work.
The table I need to delete from is Subscriptions, where ContentID = Item.Id.
Should it be double equal sign?
And it seems that it does not reach the SQL code. Just tested, it does not reach the sql command, as far as I know the script stops afer "request.execute();"?

Comment: Disregard the one above.I got it working thank you so much!
I just want to clarify or make sure I understand correctly. This function uses Only SQL functions and therefore does not start the server scripts ?

Comment: @JTIM it's a kind of trigger. You delete the parent register, and this script will delete the child.